# Calling @Published not updating in secondary view

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have a `@published var userIsLoggedIn` in my SignUpController class that gets set to true.

When I call the ObservedObject in my UserDashBoardView struct (under var Test), it doesn't seem to update. I feel I'm creating a new instance of the signUpController, which is causing the view not to update. What correction is needed in order to have the variable update in my secondary views?

Edit: added in the loginView, which when a login is successful, takes the user to the userDash View

```
class SignUpController: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var userIsLoggedIn = false
  
    func loginUser ( ) {
        userIsLoggedIn = true
    }
    
}



struct UserDashboardView: View {
        @State var selectedIndex = 0
        @ObservedObject var test = SignUpController()
        
        init(){
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            
        }
        var signUpController = SignUpController()
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                Text("Click me")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print(test.userIsLoggedIn)
                    }
            }   }
        } 
    
        
    struct userLogin: View {
        var signUpController = SignUpController()
        var body: some View {
                VStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        userLoginSuccess = true //user logged is okay
                        signUpController.loginUser() //should turn true
                    }){
                        /*
                         Navigation link symbolic, if userlogin success, will send to user dashboard view
                         
                         */
                        NavigationLink("", destination: UserDashboardView()
                                       
                                       , isActive: $userLoginSuccess)
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to represent the issue. Where is `loginUser` called? What views are you expecting to see it in? I see you passing it by `environmentObject`, but you aren't showing where you attempt to access it at all.

Comment: So It's called on a separate view where I handle the actual logging in, but didn't include that view because I tested and the LoginUser function 100% returns a true value to userIsLoggedIn variable. But I can include that view as well for you. The userdashview is the view we go to, after they login

Comment: Ideally, you'd include a [mre].

Comment: Okay I edited the code further thank you. To recap, when the login function is called on the userLogin view, the @Published var gets toggled to true. When I call and check on the variable in the userDashboardView struct, it is still false. Just wanted to recap in case I wasn't as detailed in my post. Thanks!

Comment: You're setting `userLoginSuccess`, which doesn't seem to exist anyplace. Is there a reason you're binding to that and not directly to `$signUpController.userIsLoggedIn`?

Comment: Yea apologies, so that was just there as a placeholder in my code since I couldn't access the $signUpController.userIsLoggedIn variable

Comment: Okay, so are you actually using `$signUpController.userIsLoggedIn`? Also, it looks like you're creating multiple instances of `SignUpController` -- you need to create *one instance* and pass it by reference to other views that need it.

Comment: Yes so ideally I want signUpController.userIsLoggedIn to handled everything (in this case accessible on both views). How would I go about creating one instance in this scenario?

Comment: Have *one place* where you write `SignUpController()` and then send it as a parameter to other subviews (like `userLogin(signUpController: signUpController)`)

Comment: and thats what's throwing me for a loop, could just be I'm having one of those days. But I can't think of a way to send it as a parameter since the userIsLoggedIn is returning on a function, and I'm not passing a view from when the variable is first called.

Comment: If you update your code to show where `userLogin` is used (again, think [mre] -- something that can be *reproduced*), I can probably provide an example showing how to pass `SignUpController` (not `userIsLoggedIn`) by reference.